# JSON output for mapping data using json_decode() in php

Tags: php, drupal-6, json, openstreetmap, mapquest

I am attempting to write PHP code to interact with JSON output from Mapquest's Open API / Open Street Map service.  I have listed it below.  I have been using this code in my Drupal 6 implementation.  This code returns no output.  When I use it, `json_last_error()` outputs 0.

```
function json_test_page() {
  $url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?outFormat=json&from=40.037661,-76.305977&to=39.962532,-76.728099';
  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $obj = json_decode(var_export($json));
  $foo .= $obj->{'fuelUsed'}; 
  $output .= foo;
  return $output;
}
```

You can view the raw JSON output by [following the URL](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?outFormat=json&from=40.037661,-76.305977&to=39.962532,-76.728099).  In this function I am expecting to get `1.257899` as my output.  I have two questions:

(1) What can I call so I get items out of my array.  For instance, how can I get the value represented in JSON `"distance":26.923` out of the array?

(2) Is it possible am I running into a recursion limit issue that I've read about in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the manual page for json_decode carefully, you'll notice there is a parameter (false by default) that you can pass to have it return an array rather than an object.

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

So:

```
<?php

function json_test_page() {
    $url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?outFormat=json&from=40.037661,-76.305977&to=39.962532,-76.728099';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    //var_dump($obj);
    echo $obj['route']['fuelUsed'];
}

json_test_page();
```

Comment: This is great.  Worked as expected.  I knew about the `TRUE` parameter but I didn't know if it was best to parse the array using `json_decode()` or something else.  This seems to work just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `var_export` function from `json_decode`.

You're trying to convert information about a string to json.

I was able to get the `fuelUsed` property this way

```
function json_test_page() {
    $url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?outFormat=json&from=40.037661,-76.305977&to=39.962532,-76.728099';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    return $obj->route->fuelUsed;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, but per the original question, I offered an alternative that gets an array back.